# SQL Server 2012 error : Must declare the scalar variable @lcrcolumn_total

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

This is my first project in Dynamic SQL.

When i run the below query. I'm getting an error:

> Must declare scalar variable "

Though i declared the variable `@lcrcolumn_total` upfront.

```
EXECUTE (' UPDATE facetswrk.dbo.ODS_SUBSC_PREM_REPORT ' + ' SET ' + @lcrcolumn_name + ' = @lcrcolumn_total')
```

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: It's simple - `EXECUTE` command will execute exactly what's in it's command parameter. And it has own session, so when you are using any variables in it, it has to be declared inside this command, not outside.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass variable to dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = 
   'UPDATE facetswrk.dbo.ODS_SUBSC_PREM_REPORT 
    SET @lcrcolumn_name = @lcrcolumn_total'
    -- WHERE = ?;  -- are you sure you want to update all rows

SET @sql = REPLACE(@sql, '@lcrcolumn_name', QUOTENAME(@lcrcolumn_name)); 

EXEC dbo.sp_executesql
     @sql,
     N'@lcrcolumn_total INT',   -- set type of @lcorumn_total
     @lcrcolumn_total;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/432489)**</kbd>

Remarks:

1. Add `WHERE` condition otherwise you will update all rows
2. Use [`sp_executesql`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx) instead of `EXEC`
3. Pass variable `@lcrcolumn_total` with correct datatype
4. Use [`QUOTENAME`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176114.aspx) to avoid SQL Injection, when replacing column_name

Comment: **For downvoter, please leave a comment why do you think that this answer is not correct/helpful**

Comment: . . Your answer definitely does not deserve a downvote.  It is correct, and if I had read it first, I would not have bothered answering.

Comment: Same error is throwing as "Must declare scalar variable".I didn't downvote you either. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are learning dynamic SQL, then just learn to use `sp_executesql`, because it is the best way to execute such statement.  It allows you to pass arguments in and out.  This is important because the "exec" statement does not share variables with the outer context.

The code would look more like this:

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max);

SET @sql = '
UPDATE facetswrk.dbo.ODS_SUBSC_PREM_REPORT
    SET @lcrcolumn_name = @lcrcolumn_total
';

SET @sql = REPLACE(@sql, '@lcrcolumn_name', @lcrcolumn_name);

EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@lcrcolumn_total int', @lcrcolumn_total = @lcrcolumn_total;
```

Note that you cannot pass column and table names as parameters, so these are handled using `REPLACE()`.

Comment: I used you query and got an below error.                                                       Procedure expects parameter @params of type 'ntext/nchar/nvarchar'

Comment: And you need to declare and initialize `@lcrcolumn_total`